# Animal rights violation in Germany

Tags: germany, animals

How can I report animal right violation that takes place in the business located in Germany? It’s a beauty salon that uses animals for some treatments.

I live outside Germany and unfortunately have no relatives there who could help or advise me.

Comment: some animals are working animals. that is not an animal right violation.

Comment: You are right, but in that case it *is* a violation.

Comment: German site that might help: https://www.tierschutzbuero.de/ratgeber-tierleid/ - note that the simple allegation might not trigger the regulatng body to intervene.

Comment: How did you witness these violations? Do you have any proof? Is this hearsay or first-hand knowledge?

Comment: The complete lack of detail for what the animal is being used for will probably not bring any useful answer. Depending on those details, the **health department** (Gesundheitsamt) is the first choice  to report such an affair. They would then pass it on if outside their scope of responsibility.

Comment: "uses animals for some treatments" - that could be anything, from entirely harmless to absolutely evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is it indeed an “animal right violation”?
  Germany’s [Animal Welfare Act](http://bundesrecht.juris.de/tierschg) is the primary law protecting animals.
  According to § 17 it is a crime to

  - kill vertebrate animals “without good cause”, or to
  - inflict significant pain on vertebrate animals

    - out of sheer crudeness, or
    - on a regular basis or for a prolonged period.
- If you suspect someone of a crime, you can report it to the authorities.
  Most state polices now have an “online police station”, for instance [Lower Saxony](https://www.onlinewache.polizei.niedersachsen.de/).
  Choose the police station of the right state.
  You can also call a police station or the DA’s office if telephone charges weren’t an issue, but snailmail is always an option.
- However, since you wrote that the “beauty salon […] uses animals for some treatments” I imagine the animals aren’t subject to excessive pain while patrons receive their treatment.

  Commercial operations with animals have to obey *lots* of rules, too many to list them.
  Breaking them usually constitutes an administrative offense (*Ordnungswidrigkeit*).
  Repeated violations could justify a revocation of relevant permissions.
- If you got reason to believe someone committed an administrative offense, you can report it to the public order office, the *Ordnungsamt*.
  The public order office is *usually* a department of the city.
  In *some* places the *veterinary office* is responsible for dealing with animal welfare administrative offenses, but unless you know I’d address *the city* which will forward your report.